# Github Integration Magically Disappears when I do a code commit (Github Pull Request Plugin)

Tags: git, github, jenkins

So, I'm trying to set up a CI job in jenkins to perform a build and report the status on every PR in my repo.

I was able to get this working when I point it to a specific branch, but when I follow the documentation, it somehow deletes my github integration service in my account and refuses to build my PR.

(Reference: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin)

Steps to Reproduce:

1. In github (https://github.com/XXX/YYY/settings/installations) add the `Jenkins (Github plugin)` service.  Put in the correct URL.
2. In the jenkins job, set refspec to `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*`
3. Set branch to `${sha1}`
4. Put in a code commit in your repo and push

Result: No build is executed, but the service gets deleted from the account...

Note: Leaving refspec empty and setting branch to `*/feature-branch` works perfectly fine.